# How can I control Javascript execution order?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I'm having some concurrency issues with a webpage I'm building. Basically, I have three script files that I'm using to hold some data:

**script1.js:**

```
var myValue = 1;
```

**script2.js:**

```
var myValue = 2;
```

**script3.js:**

```
var myValue = 3;
```

And I have one page, **mypage.html** that basically looks like this:

```
<html>
<script>
   function get_number()
   {
     var script_file = GetQueryStringValue( "run" );
     e = document.createElement('script');
     e.type='text/javascript';
     e.src = script_file + ".js"
     head.appendChild( e );

     document.write( myValue );
   }
</script>
<body onload="get_number()">
   <div onclick="get_number()">Click me!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main idea with this page is that you would query it like this:
    `mypage.html?run=script1`
which would tell the `get_number()` function to dynamically insert `script1.js` in to mypage.htm. Then, I call `get_number()` to display the value loaded from the script.

Now, I've stripped down the above to what I think are the relevant parts and I've left out a bunch of stuff, obviously. My actual code loads a large array of values and is more interesting... But, I'm hoping someone can help me out with this regardless.

What I'm finding is that in IE, the number displays correctly.

In Firefox, Chrome and Safari, I get an error that `myValue` is undefined. However, if I click the `Click me` div that I created, the number displays correctly. So, I know I'm correctly loading the javascript external file. But, it just isn't loaded in time for my `get_number()` function to work correctly `onload`.

Now, I hacked up my file a little so that the `get_number` function looks like this:

```
 function get_number()
 {
   var script_file = GetQueryStringValue( "run" );
   e = document.createElement('script');
   e.type='text/javascript';
   e.src = script_file + ".js"
   head.appendChild( e );

   setTimeout( function() { document.write( myValue ), 10 } );
 }
```

The setTimeout delays enough for the DOM to be updated and the javascript to be loaded in most cases. But, this is a total hack. Firefox tends to load this 'improved' code correctly all the time while Chrome and Safari manage to get the value about 50% of the time.

So, I guess I'm wondering, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? It's very important that the value be driven externally (by the query string), but other than that requirement, I'm very flexible.

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/articles/stratifiedjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you possibly add a function call to your script files, so that when they're run, they call the function that does your

```
document.write( myValue );
```

So that script1.js would be

```
var myValue = 1;
scriptLoaded();
```

and your main file would have:

```
function scriptLoaded(){
   document.write( myValue );
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with because it proved to be so simple. I feel somewhat silly that I didn't think of this myself!

Thanks for the other replies, though. They were all actually workable and would have solved me problem.

Answer (score 6):

This method of dynamically loading script files using DOM methods like head.appendChild is asynchronous, meaning that the page does not wait for it to load before running any further code.  If you did not want this asynchronous behaviour, you could load them with regular  elements in your HTML, or you could mess around with a 'synchronous' XMLHttpRequest to grab it and eval() to run it.

You probably don't want to do that, though, because being asynchronous makes the entire page load faster, anyway.  You will probably just need to add some logic that waits for the dynamically loaded script to have loaded before you go on with the next bit of code.  This may, however, involve polling using setInterval() until you notice a variable from the included script has been defined.  Or, you could add code in the included script that calls a method to whatever has been waiting for it.

Or, you could look at how jQuery does something similar, look for where the ajax method is defined, specifically these parts...

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

// then later ...

script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
    this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {

        // do processing
            head.removeChild( script );
    }
};

// ...

head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Do you think the word asynchronous is actually being used incorrectly by most people? I mean, you would think that asynchronous would mean that things don't happen together or at the same time, that would be synchronous. But people use it with the opposite meaning.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen people use it with the opposite meaning - what were you referring to?
By the way, polling as described in this answer is probably no longer necessary as XMLHttpRequest works better and is more supported now.