# Running JavaScript in a UIWebView before any other JavaScript is run

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, code-injection

I have a UIWebView component that is going to load a webpage which might contain JavaScript. I want to run some JavaScript of my own before any JavaScript on the loaded webpage runs. I know I can use `[myWebView stringByEvaulatingJavaScriptFromString:]` on the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate of the `UIWebView`, however this will only run my JavaScript *after* the JavaScript on the webpage is run.

Is the only solution to inject my JavaScript into the source code of the webpage? For example, I would put it immediately after the `<head>` tag to insure it is the first JavaScript that is run.

Answer (score 5):

I would like an answer to this question as well.  I can get it to work for the initial loading of the page by putting `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js]` inside `webViewDidStartLoad`.  On refresh, however, it does not appear to work.

**Edit:** I found this work-around (similar to the suggestion in your question.)  Not sure how robust it is.  http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/

Answer (score 1):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708449/how-can-i-control-javascript-execution-order) about JS execution order. There is another [tutorial](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/exeorder.htm) here for the same issue. If you have a problem with a specific piece of code add it here in a detailed example and will see what it can be done.

Comment: I think this is more of a question about how to inject javascript into a UIWebView in iOS rather than a strict javascript ordering question.